# A tricky VI / VIM remapping question

Tags: vim, editor, text-editor, vi

I am trying out Debian on a VM and for some reason the (default) mapping in VIM to get into visual block mode is `CTRL-SHIFT-V`.

Problem is:

I can't find documentation to remap this specific case anywhere, so any advice welcome.

Comment: It was my understanding that Ctrl+V and Ctrl+Shift+V were returning the same key code anyway. So it should not make a difference. To test if there is any difference : go in Insert mode, type Ctr+V, then your key combination, you should see the returned character displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows `CTRL-V` could be mapped to paste text.

From `:h CTRL-V-alternative`:

> Since CTRL-V is used to paste, you
>   can't use it to start a blockwise
>   Visual selection.  You can use CTRL-Q
>   instead.  You can also use CTRL-Q in
>   Insert mode and Command-line mode to
>   get the old meaning of CTRL-V.  But
>   CTRL-Q doesn't work for terminals when
>   it's used for control flow.